# How does a Gradient points to the steepest ascent of a curve?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

What I understand about a **Gradient** is:

> *A gradient is an angle which points to the direction of the steepest ascent of a curve.*
>
> Let us take a look at the plot of the following function:
>
> $$ \bbox[lightgray] {f(x) = -x^2+4}\qquad (1)$$
>
> [image]
>
> The 1st derivative of the function is:
>
> $$ \bbox[lightgray] {\frac{dy}{dx} = -2x}\qquad (2)$$
>
> Putting $x=-1$ in $(2)$ we obtain,
>
> $\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{rise}{run}= 2$
>   $\implies tan \theta = 2$
>   $\implies \theta = tan^{-1}(2)$
>   $\implies \theta = 0.964 $ radian
>
> So, $\theta = 55.23 ^\circ$
>
> Similarly, putting $x=-2$ in $(2)$ we obtain,
>
> So, $\theta = 57.25 ^\circ$
>
> [image]

Now, as we can see, **red** and **blue** lines are representative of two angles which represent the ascent of the curve at points  $(-1, 3)$ and $(-2, 0)$ respectively.

So, my question is, **How are these two angles pointing towards the steepest ascent (Coz, these are just angles. They are not pointing towards anything)**?

Comment: Sure they are, follow the red line in the direction $55.23^\circ$ and you will reach the maximum

Comment: @caverac, I can follow the line to the direction of $-y$ also as the line runs to both directions.

Comment: Yes, but following in the direction of $-y$ is a different angle, it is $235.23^\circ$, which is not the angle you calculated